# Access complex Javascript object in Java GraalVM

Tags: javascript, java, graalvm, graaljs

I have a use case where I have a java Map which I convert into ProxyMap, use that map in javascript using context.eval and then create a new object in js (nested json). Now I want to use the object that was created in javascript back in java preferably a Map.

Now my js created object is dynamic and I do not know what all fields might be present.

So basically what I am doing is:

1. `context.getBindings("js").putMember("input", ProxyObject.fromMap(map));`
2. `Value js = context.eval("js", "var obj = {'a':input['type']};");`
3. Now I need to get this `obj` as a Map in Java.

From what I have found out is that I can access the fields of `obj` in java using `getMember` but as `obj` can be dynamic and can be quite complex as well, I was hoping that there might be another way out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert to a `Map` using the `Value.as(Map.class)` [method](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Value.html#as-java.lang.Class-).

Something like:

```
 assert context.eval("js", "({foo:'bar'})").as(Map.class).get("foo").equals("bar");
```